# React Native - TouchableOpacity causing app to crash on Android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a simple component that toggles between two sets of items - Hours & Happy Hours. The component works fine on iOS, but causes my app to crash (silently) on Android.

I have a working example here: https://snack.expo.io/Sk92sIEmf. And here is the code used, for reference:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showAnother: true,
      oneThingActive: false,
      anotherActive: true,
    };
  }

  handlePress = () => {
    const { anotherActive, oneThingActive } = this.state
    return this.setState({ anotherActive: !anotherActive, oneThingActive: !oneThingActive });
  }

  render() {

    const { showAnother, oneThingActive, anotherActive  } = this.state

    return (
      <View style={s.container}>
        <View style={s.sRow}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={s.titleCont} activeOpacity='1' onPress={this.handlePress}>
            <Text style={[s.text, s.title, !oneThingActive && s.inactive]}>ONE THING</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          { showAnother &&
            <Text style={[s.text, s.title]}>|</Text>
          }
          { showAnother &&
            <TouchableOpacity style={s.titleCont} activeOpacity='1' onPress={this.handlePress}>
              <Text style={[s.text, s.title, !anotherActive && s.inactive]}>ANOTHER</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          }
        </View>
        { oneThingActive &&
          <View style={s.row}>
            <Text style={[s.text, s.day]}>testing..</Text>
          </View>
        }
        { anotherActive &&
          <View style={s.row}>
            <Text style={[s.text, s.day]}>123..</Text>
          </View>
        }
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const s = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginHorizontal: 35,
    marginVertical: 5,
    borderColor: '#D4D4D4',
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
  },
  titleCont: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
  },
  title: {
    color: '#232323',
    fontSize: 14,
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    marginHorizontal: 5,
  },
  text: {
    color: '#232323',
    fontSize: 13,
  },
  inactive: {
    color: '#95989A',
  },
  row: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  sRow: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: width,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingBottom: 5,
  },
})
```

As stated earlier, I don't really get an error when this crashes. At one point, I saw something to the effect of "*attempted to assign read only property*," but I am no longer seeing that error message. Any help or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks !

**Edit:**

Updated with a simplified example. It seems the crash is coming from the conditional render (`this.state.oneThingActive && ...`), a pattern I frequently use and have not run into any issues like this with.

The best way to reproduce is to visit this link: https://snack.expo.io/Sk92sIEmf, which has an IDE setup for React Native apps. You should find that the toggle works fine when the Platform is iOS, but once a state change is attempted in the Android version the app crashes.

**Edit 2:**

Seems the problem was due to the usage of `TouchableOpacity`.... I noticed the Android app was crashing from a `console.log("...")`, so I tried swapping in `TouchableHighlight` and got it to work. 
Going to investigate this more over the coming days, but would love to hear input if anyone has some.

**Answer**

This all seems a bit silly now, but my error was getting caused by `activeOpacity='1'`. I was passing in 1 as a `String` instead of as a `Number`. `activeOpacity={1}`does the trick. Do yourself a favor (unlike me in this instance) and use a linter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just encountered the same thing. In my case it was an issue of it not liking quotes in my style. Not sure about your case, but in my case when I added a

```
style={{marginRight: "20px"}}
```

by mistake it crashed. I should have had

```
style={{marginRight: 20}}
```

instead. Even just having

```
style={{marginRight: '20'}}
```

or

```
{{marginRight: "20"}}
```

causes it to crash.

I notice that you have `activeOpacity='1'` in your code and am wondering if you remove the quotes around the `1` whether it solve your problem.

Comment: yep. never updated this. activeOpacity={1} did the trick, was bummed I didn't get a warning for that

Comment: @pingo Yes, it's a bit baffling. I also find it strange that not many other people are encountering this issue. I have posted a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49377452/quotes-around-numeric-style-values-cause-app-to-crash - glad that worked for you!

Comment: RN noob here. Do you have to create two codebases for 1 app just so it could compile it for iOS / Android? I mean I see the usage of two different buttons for both platforms. I was assuming RN would handle that.

Comment: @AliGajani It's better to ask this as a new question. Be sure to link to any sites/pages as to why you are questioning this.

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a problem with the fact that class methods are not automatically bound to the instance. Add these to your constructor:

```
this.hoursPressed = this.hoursPressed.bind(this);
this.happyHoursPressed = this.happyHoursPressed.bind(this);
```

This is a common problem with using ES6 classes with React.

Comment: This isn't the issue. The methods are properly bound. Note that the definition is `hoursPressed = () => {` not `hoursPressed() {`

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that.