# Quotes around numeric style values cause app to crash

Tags: react-native

I have the following section of code. When I put quotes (either single quotes around the integer values in the sections of code marked with `Issue n` my app crashes without any apparent error message. As soon as I navigate to that page I get a popup box that says: "Unfortunately ExampleApp has stopped." with an "OK" button.

Adding quotes to any of the four marked sections below causes the app to crash. However, if I add quotes around the flex integer, I get a proper error thrown and a red screen is displayed on my phone with the message: `Invariant Violation: Invalid prop 'flex' of type 'string' supplied to 'StyleSheet container', expected 'number'.`

```
render(){


    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 0, //No Issue
        padding: 8, //Issue 1
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#C1C1C1',
      },
      button: {
          margin: 5 //Issue 2
      }
    });

    return(

      <View style={styles.container}>

        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.goHome()} style={{marginRight: 20}}> //Issue 3
                <Image source={require('../images/pic001.png')} style={{width: 30, height: 30}} /> //Issue 4
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>


        <View  style={styles.button}>
            <Button title="Select" onPress={() => this.selectItem()} />
        </View>
      </View>
    )
}
```

Is there a reason that quotes would cause my app to crash unexpectedly like this? Why do I get a proper error when the flex value is quoted, but do not get a proper error in any of the other situations.

If it helps, I am developing on Windows 10, connecting to my Android phone (with USB cable for the initial connection).

See also [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48026680/react-native-touchableopacity-causing-app-to-crash-on-android/49377226) for a similar problem.